# Single value type from nested object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is the following object:

```
export const SCENES = {
  GREETING: 'scene:greeting',
  PROFILE: 'scene:profile',
  PURCHASES: 'scene:purchases',
  BALANCE: {
    ENTER_AMOUNT: 'scene:balance:enterAmount',
    INVOICE: 'scene:balance:invoice',
  },
};
```

There is the following interface:

```
interface ExtraInterface {
  backToStage?: something; // <--- It is required to take the value of one of the elements
}
```

How can this problem be solved? **I would be extremely grateful!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong. So you want to be able only to assign following values to `backToStage`
`'scene:greeting'|'scene:profile'|'scene:purchases'|'scene:balance:enterAmount'|'scene:balance:invoice'`

If that's the case then first you should let the TS know that `SCENES` will be readonly so it doesn't generalize types of its properties value to `string`. It can be done just by adding `as const`.

```
export const SCENES = {
  GREETING: 'scene:greeting',
  PROFILE: 'scene:profile',
  PURCHASES: 'scene:purchases',
  BALANCE: {
    ENTER_AMOUNT: 'scene:balance:enterAmount',
    INVOICE: 'scene:balance:invoice',
  },
} as const;
```

Next we are going to get all values from the `SCENES` with the following generic type:

```
type ExtractSceneValues<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? ExtractSceneValues<T[K]> : T[K];
}[keyof T];
```

This type loops through the keys and if the values are objects it will call itself recursively, otherwise it gets the value of this property (`T[K]`).
The magic part is the `[keyof T]` which creates the union type of all values, which is exactly what we need.

Full answer:

```
export const SCENES = {
  GREETING: 'scene:greeting',
  PROFILE: 'scene:profile',
  PURCHASES: 'scene:purchases',
  BALANCE: {
    ENTER_AMOUNT: 'scene:balance:enterAmount',
    INVOICE: 'scene:balance:invoice',
  },
} as const;

type ExtractSceneValues<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? ExtractSceneValues<T[K]> : T[K];
}[keyof T];

interface ExtraInterface {
  backToStage?: ExtractSceneValues<typeof SCENES>;
}
```

Comment: You my friend, are brilliant!