# Create TypeScript type from object's nested properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is the object

```
export const fieldMapping = {
  'IP': { name: 'ipAddress', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'IP Country': { name: 'country', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'IP City': { name: 'city', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'IP Continent': { name: 'continent', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'Payment Processor': {
    name: 'paymentProcessor',
    type: AirtableFieldType.STRING,
  },
};
```

**the goal is to get the following type**

```
type fieldNames = | 'ipAddress' | 'country' | 'city' | 'continent' | 'paymentProcessor';
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to add `as const` for any change of this working.

Comment: Then you can do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJxxZN).

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911681/single-value-type-from-nested-object/)

Comment: @wonderflame I agree that it's probably a duplicate, but that does not seem like a suitable dupe target.

Comment: @zenly okay, I agree

Comment: Is it expected for `fieldMapping` to be deeply nested?

Comment: only at this level

Comment: `export type fieldNames = keyof typeof fieldMapping;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be casting it as `const`.

```
const AirtableFieldType = {
    STRING: 'sample'
}

export const fieldMapping = {
  'IP': { name: 'ipAddress', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'IP Country': { name: 'country', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'IP City': { name: 'city', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'IP Continent': { name: 'continent', type: AirtableFieldType.STRING },
  'Payment Processor': {
    name: 'paymentProcessor',
    type: AirtableFieldType.STRING,
  },
} as const;


type FieldKeys = keyof typeof fieldMapping // get all the keys of fieldMapping
type FieldMapping = (typeof fieldMapping)[FieldKeys]['name'] // 'ipAddress' | 'country' | 'city' | 'continent' | 'paymentProcessor'
```

Demo TypeScript:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQQJYCcYEMBGAbApgMSV2wBMAVATwAdc4BeOAb2DlbgGUyAlASQDkA4gC44AcijoAtlTyjgAX2DBcADypg0ccNHgAzIqQCy6KlSQQA5vSYsxPAAqiRjOBCm4RopFQQkSKXCgoUQAaOBhqD0RUDBwCA3JIgDpOXkE4eRDbUQc4AGEwAFcIGBQKJyZXd09wYtLysIiaEWQ0LDxCYkSaFO5+AQys1hz7fKQIipc3SSjREHGG8MiWmPb4rsoe1P7B7NyCkvNcEsmqmZrIGCOTxuXotrjO0k3cXrSBzOz7dAoZkrh7CgwCBAlANJNbKxprMqD8-jBAcDQeChmwmlFWrEOgkXm9+qjPvI4OgoFpILAANxKYDouBPEgAaVwFFJDAA1sywLoljQuXB9F1jKZzBYaZE6QkhSLrAAKdF8gVGExmSwASgA2vSmSyALrq0TQ0Q64BAA

Comment: It worked, thank you. The problem now i face is that it type can't be used as `{[key:FieldMapping]:any}`  it gives me the following error                                                   
"An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead"